# How to add next and previous buttons

Tags: jquery

Am working on a tab content and have tried many techniques to make the next and prev buttons work but couldn't.
I tried:

```
$(".tabs").tabs(); 
$("#next").click(function () {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", $(".tabs").tabs('option', 'active')+1 );
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", $(".tabs").tabs('option', 'active')-1 );
});
```

Where did I go wrong and how can I make it work?
Below is fiddle of how it looks
http://jsfiddle.net/6ptuq02z/1/

Comment: Your fiddle is neigh unreadable and is not a minimum case.  Anyway, `-1` cannot be applied to a jQuery object.  You are probably looking for the `next()` and `prev()` sibling methods. http://api.jquery.com/next/ http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: You're not supposed to call `.tabs()` on the `<ul>`. You're supposed to call it on the `<ul>`'s parent, which contains the tab bodies.

Comment: I will appreciate supporting your answers with fiddle if posible

Comment: @Draco18s FYI, neigh = sound a horse makes; nigh = near, almost :)

Comment: I speel gud. :B I ty[e well, too.

Comment: @MRSalim it appears as though you've copied some minified code into jsfiddle.net. I personally would not attempt to edit that and provide updated code. There is a Tidy button in the toolbar of jsfiddle.net that will format your code for you. When I do that, I notice that the code in your jsfiddle does not match the code in your question. This indicates a disconnect between what you are asking and your code, which makes this a bad question. Update one or the other so they match, and then someone might be able to answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I created that fiddle. But in the fiddle I didn't include the code shared above as it didn't worked. Also am new to creating fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function named `tabs()` in your `js`. You can add next and previous click like following.

```
$(function () {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        $(".tabs li.selected").next('li').find('a').click()
    });

    $("#back").click(function () {
        $(".tabs li.selected").prev('li').find('a').click();
    });
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ptuq02z/2/